# How to get Symbol attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I executed following code

```
var x={};
x[Symbol("a")] = "a";
x.d = "d";
```

When I try in browser console

```
console.log(x); //Object {d: "d", Symbol(a): "a"}

JSON.stringify(x); //"{"d":"d"}"

var a=Symbol("a");
console.log(x[a]); //undefined

console.log(x['a']); //undefined
```

> I'm little bit confused how will I get the second attribute of variable x which is a symbol

Comment: As the fast question you posted (and deleted), is your browser compatible with ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)? Because the method exists: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to recover those symbols first.

```
var x = {};
x[Symbol("a")] = "a";
x.d = "d";
symbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(x);

console.log( symbols ); //will output [Symbol("a")]
```

Since symbols are used for debugging, they don't show as a normal attribute, even when normally iterating through the Object.

To get the value of the Symbol, once gotten the Symbols properties, you can do:

```
console.log( x[ symbols[0] ] );
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/730q04bw/1/

Comment: console.log(x[symbols]); //still console undefined

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Where are you running this? Works for me in latest Chrome stable: http://jsfiddle.net/730q04bw/ and also [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Ax%5BSymbol(%22a%22)%5D%20%3D%20%22a%22%3B%0D%0Ax.d%20%3D%20%22d%22%3B%0D%0Avar%20symbols%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(x)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%20x%5Bsymbols%5B0%5D%5D%20)%3B%20%2F%2Fwill%20output%20%5BSymbol(%22a%22)%5D)

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Does your browser support ES6 specification?

Comment: console.log( symbols ); // gives output Symbol("a")

Comment: but console.log(x[symbols]); //still console undefined

Comment: I also want value of property Symbol("a")

Comment: I recommend you to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol.
About retrieving the value of the symbol, you can do `console.log(x[symbols[0]])` an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/730q04bw/1/